# Flex/BlazeDS Producer Consumer - Stop producing client from receiving from a consumer

Tags: apache-flex, air, blazeds, producer-consumer

I am currently working with Flex 4.9 (Mobile App) and BlazeDS integrated with ColdFusion. I have created a simple producer/consumer application where is sends up the object to the server, stores the object, then sends the object to all the connected clients. This is working very well.

However, my only issue is that the client who sent the object, is also receiving it right back. I would prefer this not happen.  Is there anyway on the client side, to distinguish if you are the originator.

I understand that the event from the consumer has an originatorID but I have no idea what to match the ID too on return.

Message Handler:

```
protected function consumer_messageHandler(event:MessageEvent):void
        {//Need to check if client is the same HERE


            var t:Object = event.message.body.ticket;
            var i:ArrayCollection = event.message.body.TI;

            if (t != null && t.length > 0)
            {
                var v:views.delivery.HomeView = this.mainNav.activeView as views.delivery.HomeView;
                var dao:DTDAO = new DTDAO();

                var t:Object = t.getItemAt(0);

                dao.syncDeliveryT(ticket, items);
            }
        }
```